# Vertices and edges Animation in graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations, animate

I have done animation in edges in the following graph. I also want to highlight vertices by animation. I want to do both animation one after another. First vertices animation then edges animation. Please guide me for the same.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{40}
\multiframe{200}{n=0+0.005}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (7,0)[line width=1pt]--(11,0);
\draw (7,0)[line width=1pt]--(7,4);
\draw (7,4)[line width=1pt]--(11,4);
\draw (11,0)[line width=1pt]--(11,4);
\draw (7,0)[white,line width=1pt]--(8,1);
\draw (7,4)[white,line width=1pt]--(8,3);
\draw (11,0)[white,line width=1pt]--(10,1);
\draw (11,4)[white,line width=1pt]--(10,3);
\draw (8,1)[line width=1pt]--(8,3);
\draw (8,1)[line width=1pt]--(10,1);
\draw (10,1)[line width=1pt]--(10,3);
\draw (8,3)[line width=1pt]--(10,3);
\draw (7,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,3);
\draw (7,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,1);
\draw (7,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,1);
\draw (7,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,3);
\draw (11,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,3);
\draw (11,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,1);
\draw (11,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,3);
\draw (11,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,1);
\draw(7,4) [fill=black] circle (3pt);
\draw(11,4) [fill=black] circle (3pt);
\draw(7,0) [fill=black] circle (3pt);
\draw(11,0) [fill=black] circle (3pt) ;
\draw(8,1) [fill=black] circle (3pt);
\draw(8,3) [fill=black] circle (3pt);
\draw(10,1) [fill=black] circle (3pt);
\draw(10,3) [fill=black] circle (3pt);
 \begin{scope}[fill opacity=4]
    \filldraw[fill=blue,draw=red,line width=1pt] (7,0)--(7+\n,0+\n);
    \filldraw[fill=blue,draw=red,line width=1pt] (7,4)--(7+\n, 4-\n);
    \filldraw[fill=blue,draw=red,line width=1pt] (11,0)--(11-\n, 0+\n);
    \filldraw[fill=blue,draw=red,line width=1pt] (11,4)--(11-\n, 4-\n);
\end{scope}


 \draw(7,0)node[left=2pt]{\Large $v_2'$};
 \draw(7,4)node[left=2pt]{\Large $v_1'$};
 \draw(11,0)node[right=2pt]{\Large $v_3'$};
 \draw(11,4)node[right=2pt]{\Large $v_4'$};
 \draw(8,1)node[left=2pt]{ $v_2$};
 \draw(8,3)node[left=2pt]{ $v_1$};
 \draw(10,1)node[right=2pt]{ $v_3$};
 \draw(10,3)node[right=2pt]{ $v_4$};
 \draw(9,0)node[below=7mm]{$D_2^*(C_4)$};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  \end{animateinline}
  \end{center}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: That looks nice! What kind of vertex animation do you have in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proposal. First the vertices grow and then the edges (as in your code).

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{40}
\multiframe{200}{n=-0.5+0.005}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (7,0)[line width=1pt]--(11,0);
\draw (7,0)[line width=1pt]--(7,4);
\draw (7,4)[line width=1pt]--(11,4);
\draw (11,0)[line width=1pt]--(11,4);
\draw (7,0)[white,line width=1pt]--(8,1);
\draw (7,4)[white,line width=1pt]--(8,3);
\draw (11,0)[white,line width=1pt]--(10,1);
\draw (11,4)[white,line width=1pt]--(10,3);
\draw (8,1)[line width=1pt]--(8,3);
\draw (8,1)[line width=1pt]--(10,1);
\draw (10,1)[line width=1pt]--(10,3);
\draw (8,3)[line width=1pt]--(10,3);
\draw (7,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,3);
\draw (7,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,1);
\draw (7,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,1);
\draw (7,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,3);
\draw (11,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,3);
\draw (11,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,1);
\draw (11,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,3);
\draw (11,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,1);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{ifthenelse(\n<0,6*(0.5+\n),3)} % animates as long as \n is negative
\draw(7,4) [fill=black] circle ({\k*1pt});
\draw(11,4) [fill=black] circle ({\k*1pt});
\draw(7,0) [fill=black] circle ({\k*1pt});
\draw(11,0) [fill=black] circle ({\k*1pt}) ;
\draw(8,1) [fill=black] circle ({\k*1pt});
\draw(8,3) [fill=black] circle ({\k*1pt});
\draw(10,1) [fill=black] circle ({\k*1pt});
\draw(10,3) [fill=black] circle ({\k*1pt});
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{2*max(\n,0)} % <-animation will only start when \n is positive
\begin{scope}[fill opacity=4]
    \filldraw[fill=blue,draw=red,line width=1pt] (7,0)--(7+\m,0+\m);
    \filldraw[fill=blue,draw=red,line width=1pt] (7,4)--(7+\m, 4-\m);
    \filldraw[fill=blue,draw=red,line width=1pt] (11,0)--(11-\m, 0+\m);
    \filldraw[fill=blue,draw=red,line width=1pt] (11,4)--(11-\m, 4-\m);
\end{scope}
 \draw(7,0)node[left=2pt]{\Large $v_2'$};
 \draw(7,4)node[left=2pt]{\Large $v_1'$};
 \draw(11,0)node[right=2pt]{\Large $v_3'$};
 \draw(11,4)node[right=2pt]{\Large $v_4'$};
 \draw(8,1)node[left=2pt]{ $v_2$};
 \draw(8,3)node[left=2pt]{ $v_1$};
 \draw(10,1)node[right=2pt]{ $v_3$};
 \draw(10,3)node[right=2pt]{ $v_4$};
 \draw(9,0)node[below=7mm]{$D_2^*(C_4)$};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I do the animation one after another? First Vertices then the edges?

Comment: Yes, see the [↗other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419938).

Answer (score 2):

Multiple `\multiframe`, separated by `\newframe[*]`, can be placed in an `animateinline` environment. This allows you to divide the animation into several parts. Using the starred `\newframe*` instead of `\newframe` inserts a pause between two parts (as requested in the [↗comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419900/vertices-and-edges-animation-in-graph/419938#comment1050913_419907)). The animation continues upon click.

Besides rational numbers (prefix `n`), the second argument of `\multiframe` can also define dimensions (prefix `d`) as loop variables. This was used to simplify the code a bit. Also, the computations involving `ifthenelse(...)` could be removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\newcommand\staticParts{%
  \draw (7,0)[line width=1pt]--(11,0);
  \draw (7,0)[line width=1pt]--(7,4);
  \draw (7,4)[line width=1pt]--(11,4);
  \draw (11,0)[line width=1pt]--(11,4);
  \draw (7,0)[white,line width=1pt]--(8,1);
  \draw (7,4)[white,line width=1pt]--(8,3);
  \draw (11,0)[white,line width=1pt]--(10,1);
  \draw (11,4)[white,line width=1pt]--(10,3);
  \draw (8,1)[line width=1pt]--(8,3);
  \draw (8,1)[line width=1pt]--(10,1);
  \draw (10,1)[line width=1pt]--(10,3);
  \draw (8,3)[line width=1pt]--(10,3);
  \draw (7,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,3);
  \draw (7,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,1);
  \draw (7,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,1);
  \draw (7,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,3);
  \draw (11,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,3);
  \draw (11,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,1);
  \draw (11,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,3);
  \draw (11,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,1);
  \draw(7,0)node[left=2pt]{\Large $v_2'$};
  \draw(7,4)node[left=2pt]{\Large $v_1'$};
  \draw(11,0)node[right=2pt]{\Large $v_3'$};
  \draw(11,4)node[right=2pt]{\Large $v_4'$};
  \draw(8,1)node[left=2pt]{ $v_2$};
  \draw(8,3)node[left=2pt]{ $v_1$};
  \draw(10,1)node[right=2pt]{ $v_3$};
  \draw(10,3)node[right=2pt]{ $v_4$};
  \draw(9,0)node[below=7mm]{$D_2^*(C_4)$};
}

\newcommand\vertices[1]{%
  \draw(7,4) [fill=black] circle (#1);
  \draw(11,4) [fill=black] circle (#1);
  \draw(7,0) [fill=black] circle (#1);
  \draw(11,0) [fill=black] circle (#1);
  \draw(8,1) [fill=black] circle (#1);
  \draw(8,3) [fill=black] circle (#1);
  \draw(10,1) [fill=black] circle (#1);
  \draw(10,3) [fill=black] circle (#1);
}

\newcommand\edges[1]{%
  \draw[draw=red,line width=1pt] (7,0)--(7+#1,0+#1);
  \draw[draw=red,line width=1pt] (7,4)--(7+#1, 4-#1);
  \draw[draw=red,line width=1pt] (11,0)--(11-#1, 0+#1);
  \draw[draw=red,line width=1pt] (11,4)--(11-#1, 4-#1);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{40}
\multiframe{101}{d=0pt+0.03pt}{ %d=0pt,0.03pt,...,3pt
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \staticParts
  \vertices{\d}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newframe*    %insert pause, click to continue
\multiframe{101}{n=0.0+0.01}{    %n=0,0.01,...,1.0
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \staticParts
  \edges{\n}
  \vertices{3pt}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP asked already another question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419925/121799). One possible scenario would be to copy or move your answer there.