# Auto play animation on vertices but not on edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations, animate

I want to put autoplay on vertices animation(a bit faster if possible)  but not on edges animation. Plese, guide me for the same.

```
\begin{animateinline}{40}
\multiframe{200}{n=0+0.005}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (7,0)[line width=1pt]--(11,0);
\draw (7,0)[line width=1pt]--(7,4);
\draw (7,4)[line width=1pt]--(11,4);
\draw (11,0)[line width=1pt]--(11,4);
\draw (7,0)[white,line width=1pt]--(8,1);
\draw (7,4)[white,line width=1pt]--(8,3);
\draw (11,0)[white,line width=1pt]--(10,1);
\draw (11,4)[white,line width=1pt]--(10,3);
\draw (8,1)[line width=1pt]--(8,3);
\draw (8,1)[line width=1pt]--(10,1);
\draw (10,1)[line width=1pt]--(10,3);
\draw (8,3)[line width=1pt]--(10,3);
\draw(7,4) [fill=red] circle (3pt);
\draw(11,4) [fill=red] circle (3pt);
\draw(7,0) [fill=red] circle (3pt);
\draw(11,0) [fill=red] circle (3pt) ;
\draw(8,1) [fill=red] circle (3pt);
\draw(8,3) [fill=red] circle (3pt);
\draw(10,1) [fill=red] circle (3pt);
\draw(10,3) [fill=red] circle (3pt);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{(3*\n} % animates as long as \n is negative
\draw(7,4) [fill=blue] circle ({\k*1.35pt});
\draw(11,4) [fill=blue] circle ({\k*1.35pt});
\draw(7,0) [fill=blue] circle ({\k*1.35pt});
\draw(11,0) [fill=blue] circle ({\k*1.35pt}) ;
 \draw(8,1) [fill=blue] circle ({\k*1.35pt});
 \draw(8,3) [fill=blue] circle ({\k*1.35pt});
 \draw(10,1) [fill=blue] circle ({\k*1.35pt});
 \draw(10,3) [fill=blue] circle ({\k*1.35pt});
%\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{\n} % <-animation will only start when \n is positive
\begin{scope}[fill opacity=4]
\filldraw[fill=blue,draw=blue,line width=1pt] (7,0)--(7+\n,0+3*\n);
\filldraw[fill=blue,draw=blue,line width=1pt] (7,0)--(7+3*\n, 0+\n);
\filldraw[fill=blue,draw=blue,line width=1pt] (7,4)--(7+\n, 4-3*\n);
\filldraw[fill=blue,draw=blue,line width=1pt] (7,4)--(7+3*\n, 4-\n);
\filldraw[fill=blue,draw=blue,line width=1pt] (11,4)--(11-3*\n, 4-\n);
\filldraw[fill=blue,draw=blue,line width=1pt] (11,4)--(11-\n, 4-3*\n); 
\filldraw[fill=blue,draw=blue,line width=1pt] (11,0)--(11-\n, 0+3*\n);
\filldraw[fill=blue,draw=blue,line width=1pt] (11,0)--(11-3*\n, 0+\n);
\end{scope}
\draw(7,0)node[red,left=2pt]{\Large $v_2'$};
\draw(7,4)node[red,left=2pt]{\Large $v_1'$};
\draw(11,0)node[red,right=2pt]{\Large $v_3'$};
\draw(11,4)node[red,right=2pt]{\Large $v_4'$};
\draw(8,1)node[red,left=2pt]{ $v_2$};
\draw(8,3)node[red,left=2pt]{ $v_1$};
\draw(10,1)node[red,right=2pt]{ $v_3$};
\draw(10,3)node[red,right=2pt]{ $v_4$};
\draw(9,0)node[below=7mm]{$D_2^*(C_4)$};
 \end{tikzpicture}}
 \end{animateinline}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of your question has already been addressed in [↗my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419938) to your previous question. The key is to use two `\multiframe` in order to divide the animation into two sections. Subsequent `\multiframes` must always be separated by a `\newframe`, but here we use the starred variant, `\newframe*`, in order to insert a pause in between. The animation continues on mouse click.

You can speed up the first animation section with the growing vertices by reducing the number of frames in this section (`101`-->`51`) and by increasing the increment (`0.03pt`-->`0.06pt`) at the same time.

(Acrobat Reader or Foxit required)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\newcommand\staticParts{%
  \draw (7,0)[line width=1pt]--(11,0);
  \draw (7,0)[line width=1pt]--(7,4);
  \draw (7,4)[line width=1pt]--(11,4);
  \draw (11,0)[line width=1pt]--(11,4);
  \draw (7,0)[white,line width=1pt]--(8,1);
  \draw (7,4)[white,line width=1pt]--(8,3);
  \draw (11,0)[white,line width=1pt]--(10,1);
  \draw (11,4)[white,line width=1pt]--(10,3);
  \draw (8,1)[line width=1pt]--(8,3);
  \draw (8,1)[line width=1pt]--(10,1);
  \draw (10,1)[line width=1pt]--(10,3);
  \draw (8,3)[line width=1pt]--(10,3);
  \draw (7,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,3);
  \draw (7,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,1);
  \draw (7,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,1);
  \draw (7,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,3);
  \draw (11,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,3);
  \draw (11,4)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,1);
  \draw (11,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(10,3);
  \draw (11,0)[blue,line width=1pt]--(8,1);
  \draw(7,0)node[left=2pt]{\Large $v_2'$};
  \draw(7,4)node[left=2pt]{\Large $v_1'$};
  \draw(11,0)node[right=2pt]{\Large $v_3'$};
  \draw(11,4)node[right=2pt]{\Large $v_4'$};
  \draw(8,1)node[left=2pt]{ $v_2$};
  \draw(8,3)node[left=2pt]{ $v_1$};
  \draw(10,1)node[right=2pt]{ $v_3$};
  \draw(10,3)node[right=2pt]{ $v_4$};
  \draw(9,0)node[below=7mm]{$D_2^*(C_4)$};
}

\newcommand\vertices[1]{%
  \draw(7,4) [fill=black] circle (#1);
  \draw(11,4) [fill=black] circle (#1);
  \draw(7,0) [fill=black] circle (#1);
  \draw(11,0) [fill=black] circle (#1);
  \draw(8,1) [fill=black] circle (#1);
  \draw(8,3) [fill=black] circle (#1);
  \draw(10,1) [fill=black] circle (#1);
  \draw(10,3) [fill=black] circle (#1);
}

\newcommand\edges[1]{%
  \draw[draw=red,line width=1pt] (7,0)--(7+#1,0+#1);
  \draw[draw=red,line width=1pt] (7,4)--(7+#1, 4-#1);
  \draw[draw=red,line width=1pt] (11,0)--(11-#1, 0+#1);
  \draw[draw=red,line width=1pt] (11,4)--(11-#1, 4-#1);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{40}
\multiframe{51}{d=0pt+0.06pt}{ %d=0pt,0.06pt,...,3pt
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \staticParts
  \vertices{\d}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newframe*    %insert pause, click to continue
\multiframe{101}{n=0.0+0.01}{    %n=0,0.01,...,1.0
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \staticParts
  \edges{\n}
  \vertices{3pt}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```